# Regex - Match only two digitsafter substring

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to replace all elements like \u00XY in a string that can contain multiple entries like that.

```
'"\u00bfIdade del titular?"'
```

This can be a short string or a string containing json objects inside... (I know... but... old code)
I tried normalize after the string but it didn't work, so I got instructed to replace all of those elements in unicode with a '?' char.

Any ideas on a simple way for this purpose? I'm not being able to find the right regex for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[0-9]{1,2}[\w]{2}?
Try this or modify it.

Comment: Is this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I made a small function that replaces all the unicode.

```
function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($sting) {
    //replace all \uxxxx for correct html equvilant
    $decoded_string = mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $sting), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
    return $decoded_string;
}
```

Hope this wil help you!